# Full print foil bag setup using InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, prepress

I have recently designed a food product bag design to be printed on a 3 seal laminated foil bag.  I produced graphics for the design in Illustrator, retouched product photography in Photoshop and laid everything out in InDesign.  The print shop apparently does not use InDesign.  Is that industry norm???  I am need to sending something like this to a press, but am finding it hard to believe that the only way to send the file would be as an .ai.  Am I crazy?

Comment: I meant to  say 'new to sending something like this to a press'.

Answer (score 1):

Any print shop should be able to use a **pdf**, which can be exported from Indesign. Make sure to export as a **Press Quality** pdf.

Comment: Yes, and then you may be able to open the PDF file in AI yourself and save as AI if that makes them happier. Just double check the details before you do so. You may need to do some re-formatting of text etc.

Answer (score 0):

A print shop requires and requests the highest resolution artwork possible.

An illustrator file is usually the best bet as far as resolution goes because of the vector based artwork.

You could recreate your layout using Illustrator and send this off to the printer.

Alternatively, ask the print shop if they will take a "Press Quality PDF" you could, depending on your artwork, create a Press Quality PDF using InDesign's export tool and selecting Press Quality. (The printer may also request bleed and trim marks.) Please see:[image: Screenshot Instructions]

Make sure all of your artwork is at least 300dpi or a vector based EPS

Note: Potentially the print shop can supply a template/specs that you could use for layout in illustrator.

Good Luck!